# How can I check a methods return value in Main?

Tags: java, methods

I'm programming a game for an assignment and I a few problems. I have a method called `validBet(boolean)` that confirms if the bet  a player makes is valid or not. I am trying to check whether the method would return true or false in my main method. If it's false, the player has to put in a new bet. Here is what I've tried to do, and my program will not even run:

```
  public static void main (String[] params) { 
     boolean rep=false;
      rep=validBet(turn,bet);
          if(rep==false){
              System.out.println("invalid bet");
              bet=Clavier.lireString();
             }
         ...
```

My question: is there something wrong with my code, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The usual way to check if a boolean is false is: `(!rep)` rather than `(rep==false)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enhance you code:

```
while(!validBet(turn,bet)){
System.out.println("invalid bet");


          bet=Clavier.lireString();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

From what I am seeing, you don't declare `rep` as a boolean (unless you do it somewhere outside of this block).

Comment: Hey, I just edited my code. I did declare, I just forgot to add it to my code here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the type of the `rep` variable. The first line of the `main` function should read:

```
boolean rep = validBet(turn, bet);
```

The second problem is that you are using the `turn` and `bet` variables without defining them first - where do they come from?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's hard to say if anything is wrong, because we probably can't see the whole code. Also, it'd be extremely useful if you provide the error/exception you get.

However, there are some potential issues:

1. `rep`, `turn` or `bet` are not declared.
2. `rep`, `turn` or `bet` are declared as non-static fields of the class and as those, they cannot be accessed from `static` method.
3. The last `}` is missing.

Also, it's not related to your issue, but you can change `rep == false` to `!rep`.

If it doesn't help, please, provide more details.

---

#### UPDATE

I can see you updated your code, so the `rep` mystery is solved, but the rest could still be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Short versión:

```
public static void main (String[] params) {     
       if(!validBet(turn,bet)){
           System.out.println("invalid bet");
           bet=Clavier.lireString();
       }
...
```